# Seeking a Gallery Plugin Compatible with Gatsby v5.12.9

Tags: gatsby

I'm working on a project with Gatsby v5.12.9 and am in search of a gallery plugin that's compatible with this specific version. I'd like to display thumbnails on a page that enlarge upon clicking and allow navigation through them.

Despite searching and trying various plugins like gatsby-theme-gallery and gatsby-gallery-simple, I've found none that work without version compatibility issues. I've been stuck for over a week and have tried various approaches.

Here are the details of my current setup configuration:

Gatsby Version: v5.12.9
Gatsby CLI Version: v5.12.4
Node Version: v18.17.1
npm Version: v10.1.0

Does anyone have a suggestion for a plugin or an alternative solution that works with Gatsby v5.12.9? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

I have tried searching with Google and also used AI, unfortunately without success.